# Is there a digital corpus somewhere of pre-Latin Vietnamese text?

Tags: corpora, written-language, analysis, vietnamese

I like as a hobby to do text processing and analysis of CJKV text.

Japanese and Chinese is of course available in near infinite quantities.

Korean is a bit harder to find, but not impossible.

Vietnamese though has not been written in Han Characters for almost a century, and prior to that time literacy was not common.

I know there have been efforts to encode characters used only in Vietnamese and not the other languages into Unicode. But what I don't know is if there's been effort to encode old documents and make them available to the public online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this project may have what you are looking for:

http://nomfoundation.org/nom-project/Digital-Library-of-Han-Nom

Comment: Indeed it does contain digitized Unicode text in parallel Chinese- and Latin- character Vietnamese. Thanks! Here's an example: [Vân Tiên Cổ Tích Tân Truyện - 雲僊古跡新傳](http://nomfoundation.org/nom-project/nom-texts/Luc-Van-Tien/59-Content_of_the_work)